# Is there a way in C to return an entire array from a function?

Tags: c, arrays

If not , what is the proper way to do this through pointers ?
For example I'm giving the function a 2-dimensional array, and then I fuse them in a linear manner.

Comment: Hundreds.. thousands duplicates.. See the related questions on the right.

Answer (score 3):

In C, arrays cannot be function parameters or function return types.

When you need array parameters, you typically pass a pointer to some array element along with additional information about the number of elements available from that point (or, rarely, a pointer to the array itself); the function thus has access to the original array elements. (The declaration syntax in C offers a visual guide for that; when you declare a function parameter as having type `T[]`, this means it has type `T *`.)

Returning is harder, since you need to decide whether to create a new array or modify the existing array in-place. Since creating a new array produces a non-local ownership responsibility, it is best for a function *not* to create this responsibility but instead require the caller to provide the output array already, via a mutable pointer.

Here's an example for that; a function that adds two arrays:

```
int * add(int const * a, int const * b, size_t len, int * out)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i != len; ++i)
        out[i] = a[i] + b[i];

    return out;     // returning the destination is traditional more than useful
}
```

Finally, it is possible to pass arrays by value if you wrap them in a struct:

```
struct Foo { int data[10]; }

struct Foo add(struct Foo a, struct Foo b)
{
    struct Foo result;
    for (size_t i = 0; i != 10; ++i)
        result.data[i] = a.data[i] + b.data[i];
    return result;
}
```

---

Here are some examples from popular platforms and the standard library on how arrays are handled:

- `strcpy`, `memcpy`: Copy one array into another; caller provides the destination
- `strdup`: Copies an array, allocates new array, caller inherits responsibility.
- `strtok`: Returns a subarray of a given array; modifies the given array in-place.
- `scanf` with `%m` format: Produces new array (of parsed input data), caller inherits responsibility.

Answer (score 0):

That's what pointers are for :)

```
void myfunction(int * ptr)
{
   ptr[0] = 5;
   ptr[1] = 6;
   etc...
}
```

then in your code:

```
int array[10];
myfunction(array);
now array[0] contain 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can return arrays in C. However, the syntax is different from other C-based languages.
In C you can't write something like this:

```
int[] foo();
```

What you have to do is understand that an array variable is a pointer to the first item of the array. So, your function would look like this:

```
int* foo();
```

A 2D array is an array of arrays. You would write it like this:

```
int** foo();
```

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: "an array variable is a pointer to the first item of the array" is misleading.  In `char ar[21]; int x = sizeof(ar)`, `x` has the value of 21.  If array variable `ar` is a pointer, then `x` would have a value like 4 or 8, etc.